# ¿Como actualizar y ejecutar el resto de la funcion?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Bueno, estoy ejecutando el siguiente codigo que modifica el contenido del iframe, y como ambas paginas estan en mi sitio esto va sin problemas (no es el problema):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="myframe" src="demo_iframe.htm"></iframe>    
<p>Click the button to change the background color of the document contained in the iframe.</p>    
<p id="demo"></p>    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>    
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var y = x.contentDocument;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

La pagina que cargo es la siguiente:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<p>This is some text in an iframe. This is some text in an iframe. This is some text in an iframe. This is some text in an iframe. This is some text in an iframe. This is some text in an iframe.</p>
</body></html>
```

Lo que importa: nesecito que al cargar mi pagina en el iframe, la pagina que cargo se actualize.

¿Como ejecutar myFunction(), actualizar la pagina y continuar con el resto de la funcion? **(sino actualiza la pagina antes de continuar con la funcion, simplemente no me sirve)**

He intentado inutilmente con el siguiente codigo, si actualiza pero no ejecuta el resto de la funcion que tambien nesecito:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myframe");

    var w = x.contentDocument;
            w.location.reload();

    var y = x.contentDocument;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @Manuel b, ¿No te sirvió la respuesta de @Einer?

Comment: no es lo que busco, ya que con onload en el iframe, pues se actualiza una y otra vez. yo solo nesecito que se actualice y cargue la funcion

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la funcion `onload` del iframe que se ejecuta cuando el iframe termina de cargar:

```
<iframe onload="myFunction()" id="myframe" src="demo_iframe.htm"></iframe>
```

Asi siempre que refresques el iframe, la funcion se ejecutara.

Comment: con onload en el iframe, se crea un bug indefinido,

Comment: Si tu función la tienes con esta línea `w.location.reload();` tienes que quitarla para evitar el bucle infinito

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías usar `onload` para hacer lo que quieres.

```
//Esta función se encargará de recargar el iFrame
function recargarIframe() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myframe"),
         w = x.contentDocument;
    w.location.reload();
}

//Esta de cambiar el color
function cambiarColor() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myframe"),
        w = x.contentDocument;
    //Cambiamos el color
    w.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

En el `HTML`:

```
<iframe onload="cambiarColor()" id="myframe" src="pagina.htm"></iframe>
```

La función `recargarIframe` se llama cuando quieras actualizar dicho `iframe`, y la función `cambiarColor` cuando el `iframe` se cargó.

Comment: gracias por el aporte, pero, nesecito que ambas se ejecuten, recargaIframe()+cambiarColor(), una despues de la otra, exactamente en ese orden. No como 2 funciones independientes. He intentedo con <button onclick="recargaIframe();cambiarColor"();">Try it</button>, y nada, se actualiza pero no se ejecuta la segunda funcion.

Comment: Hola @Manuel b, me tome el tiempo de montar un servidor usando nodejs para hacer una prueba con el ejemplo que te puse arriba, y si funciona, se ejecuta 'recargarIframe' y después 'cambiarColor', en tu botón se tendría que ejecutar 'recargarIframe' al hacer clic, y en tu etiqueta HTML tendrías que poner 'onload="cambiarColor()"', al hacer clic en tu botón, se recargaría la página de tu iframe, y se dispararía el evento 'load' de tu iframe, entonces se ejecutaría 'cambiarColor()'.

Answer (score -1):

No se si será lo que necesitas....

Yo tengo el siguiente código JS:

```
function insertarHTML() {
    var i, etiqueta, elmto, fich, llamada;
    etiqueta= document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i=0; i < etiqueta.length; i++) {
        elmto = etiqueta[i];
        fich=elmto.getAttribute("incluir-html");
        if (fich) {
            llamada = new XMLHttpRequest();
            llamada.onreadystatechange= function () {
                if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                    elmto.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    elmto.removeAttribute("incluir-html");
                    insertarHTML();
                }
            }
        llamada.open("GET", fich, true);
        llamada.send();
        return;
        }
    }
};
```

En el código HTML incluye en el tag que necesites incluir el HTML el modificador: **incluir-html="fichero_externo"** (puede usarse en cualquier tag de html iframe, div, p, span etc..)

Ademas puedes poner todos los 'incluir-html' que desees, ya que en cuanto lances la funcion **insertarHTML** se recorre y actualiza todo el DOM en modo recursivo la pagina web y te incluye todos los recursos externos HTML que hayas incluido (tb. vale para txt, etc..)

Es decir en el HTML donde quiero que se inserte el "recurso" externo pongo:

```
<html>
....
<body>
  ....
  <div incluir-html="contenido.html"></div>
   ...
 <p incluir-html="parrafo_copyleft.txt"></p>
 .... 
   <script>insertarHTML();</script>
</body>
```

El "truco final", como puedes ver está en que al final del código HTML antes de cerrar el "body" lanzar la función que se recorre todo el DOM del documento e incluye los ficheros externos.

Si no deseas que se cargue automáticamente asigna la llamada de la función a un botón y se lanzará cuando se pulse.

Comment: mmm, no obtengo el resultado deseado. solo nesecito que al hacer click en myFunction() se  altualize la pagina dentro del iframe y luego continue con la funcion. Algo con condicion, no se, como: al  hacer click se actualiza contenido en iframe y luego continue con la funcion. el codigo de carga y modificaion esta funcional, solo nesecito que al cambiar la inf con la myFunction() se actualice la pagina o el iframe

Answer (score -1):

Si necesitas una funcion y despues otra la forma mas facil seria tenerlas en un fichero javascript aparte (fichero.js) y en este escribes las dos funciones que te funcionan:

```
function Uno() {
...
}

function Dos() {
...
}
```

E incluyes una tercera función que las llame en el orden que quieres:

```
function LlamandoATodas() {
 // LLamamos de una en una a otras funciones :-D
 Una();
 Dos();
}
```

En tu HTML sólo llamas a "*LlamandoATodas();*" y ya lo tendrias...